# Unity BoxCollider - растянуть по размеру предмета

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда добавляешь BoxCollider к новому предмету, он автоматически растягивается под его размеры. Когда меняешь меш этого предмета - коллайдер не подтягивается автоматически. В api самого коллайдера никаких методов типа "AlignToSize" нет. 
Есть просто

```
 BoxCollider.size

 Use this to return or set the size of the BoxCollider component of a 
 GameObject. Unity measures the size in the GameObject's local space
```

Но если мы пишем

```
 collider.size = Vector3.one;
```

То в итоге получаем коллайдер не по размеру объекта, а просто со сторонами 1х1х1

Так как растянуть BoxCollider по размеру объекта?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При добавлении нового компонента к объекту у него(компонента) вызывается [`MonoBehaviour.Reset()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html):

> Reset to default values.
>
> Reset is called when the user hits the Reset button in the Inspector's
>   context menu or when adding the component the first time. This
>   function is only called in editor mode. Reset is most commonly used to
>   give good default values in the inspector.

Данное поведение и меняет значения размера и центра коллайдера.

---

Также нужно понимать, что вообще влияет на размеры и позицию коллайдера, в случае примитивных коллайдеров `BoxCollider/SphereCollider` - это всего 2 значения: `center`, локальное положение центра коллайдера, и `size` (radius для сферы), локальный размер(радиус) коллайдера.

Получить эти значения можно с помощью компонента `MeshFilter`, а точнее с помощью `MeshFilter.sharedMesh.bounds`:

```
Bounds bounds = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds;
BoxCollider collider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
collider.center = bounds.center;
collider.size = bounds.size;
```

---

Важно понимать, что размеры коллайдеров хранятся в **локальном пространстве** относительно объекта, к которому они прикреплены.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`MeshFilter.sharedMesh.bounds` - это AABB в **локальном пространстве**, что нам и нужно для задания размеров коллайдера.

---

Чтобы ответ был достаточно понятен для всех, объясню, что такое AABB на всякий случай.

**AABB** - ограничивающий параллелепипед выровненный по координатным осям (англ. Axis Aligned Bounding Box).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В основном он используется для рендеринга, но в данном случае он предоставляет нам фактические размеры объекта, сильно "округленные" размеры объекта, если быть точнее. Поскольку он "выровнен по осям", то угол вращения относительно всех осей у него равен нулю, но вращение нам и не нужно, оно будет вычислено после применения transform матриц, а это забота Unity, так что вручную ничего делать не нужно.